# Method invoked multiple times in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, twilio

I need to do an action in one react component. The action consists in using a framework (twilio) with the response of an API.

The problem I have is that if there are 5 components loaded, then the function will be called 5 times, one for each component even if I do the action to one only.

Here is the code:

```
  const { refetch } = useQuery(
    'chatRoom',
    () => clientAPIs.getChatRoom({ id }),
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnMount: false,
      enabled: false,
      onSuccess: async ({ room, twilioToken }) => {
        const { messageText } = getMessageText();
        // In this point it is invoked multiple times and I send the message n times
        await sendMessage(room, messageText, twilioToken.token);
        toast.success(t('COMMONS.DONE') as string);
        resetMessageForm();
      },
    }
  );
```

I invoke `refetch()` onSubmit of a form. How do you think this can be solved? I need to call **sendMessage** only once.

Comment: Will you put the `refetch` function inside just one component (that repeat 5 times) or 5 different components? Try to put `refetch` inside the top parent tree and call the function inside `useEffect()` hook

Comment: You are right! putting it into its parent is one solution

Comment: How are you invoking `refetch`? When you have 5 components on the page, are their 5 forms that you could submit?

Comment: @philnash I invoke refetch() onSubmit of a form. Basically I have the component A that includes one modal. When I open it there's a form and onSubmit I call refresh(). If I do a POST or PUT I don't have this problem.. the problem is only with useQuery.. So one solution is to convert the api into POST or move it into the parent.. I don't like no one of that but maybe I have to choose one..

Comment: Can you share a bit more context of how this is called? It would be great to see the code for what you have described.